# Сортировка элементов разных массивов

Tags: javascript, api

Я вывел список друзей из контакта, и вывел их возраст.
Как мне теперь отсортировать их по возрасту по убыванию?

Я никак додуматься не могу.

http://plnkr.co/edit/S6smJK2teK9TNegdQgZv?p=preview

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js"></script>

    <script>

    function foo() {

    VK.init({
            apiId: 5580872
        });


    VK.Auth.login(function(response){

        if(response.session){



            VK.api('friends.get', {'user_id' : '26291131', 'fields' : 'bdate'}, response => {
                if(response.error){
                    alert(response.error.error_msg);
                }
                else{
                    let userData = response.response;
                    var minAge = 0;
                    var arrUser = []
                    var arrAge;
                    var now = new Date(); 
                    var god = now.getFullYear()




                    for(var h = 0; h < userData.length; h++){
                        arrUser.push(userData[h].first_name + ' ' + userData[h].last_name)

                        if(typeof userData[h].bdate == 'string' && userData[h].bdate.split('.')[2]){
                            arrAge = userData[h].first_name + ' ' + userData[h].last_name + ' ' + (god - parseInt((userData[h].first_name + ' ' + userData[h].last_name + ' ' + userData[h].bdate.split('.')[2]).split(' ')[2]))



                            console.log(arrAge.split(' ').sort())
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }
        else{
            alert('Не удалось авторизироваться')
        }
    }, 2);
}
foo()


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

сейчас такой вид

```
    var arr = [
    ['26', 'firstname1', 'lastname1'],
    ['14', 'firstname2', 'lastname2'],
    ['22', 'firstname3', 'lastname3'],
    ['23', 'firstname4', 'lastname4'],
    ['20', 'firstname5', 'lastname5']
]
```

Как сделать вот такой?

```
var arr = [
        ['26', 'firstname1', 'lastname1'],
        ['23', 'firstname4', 'lastname4'],
        ['22', 'firstname3', 'lastname3'],
        ['20', 'firstname5', 'lastname5'],
        ['14', 'firstname2', 'lastname2']
]
```

Comment: А зачем ссылка на `http://plnkr.co/edit/S6smJK2teK9TNegdQgZv?p=preview` если там выскакивает окно **Не удалось авторизоваться** ? Может тогда уж возвращаемый json приложите?

Comment: Пишите сюда пример объекта, который надо отсортировать

Comment: Обновил тему. Пересмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: добавь пример значений которые ты сортируешь

Comment: <!-- language: lang-js --> var arr = [
  ['firstname1', 'lasname1',  '26'],
  ['firstname2', 'lastname2', '14'],
  ['firstname3', 'lasme3',    '22'],
  ['firstname3', 'laname3',   '22'],
  ['firstname4', 'lasame4',   '23'],
  ['firstname2', 'lastname2', '14'],
  ['firstname5', 'lastnme5',  '20']
];

Comment: в предыдущем вопросе уже дали ответ - и он работает. Если он не работает в твоем коде. значит либо твой код отличается. либо отличаются твои данные.

Comment: да он точно такой же

Comment: @DivMan а зачем Вы задали вопрос повторно?

Comment: там бы уже не ответили. Я обновил песочницу. Массивы, которые я сам создал, они нормально сортируются. А те которые сами подгружаются, то они не сортируются.

Comment: @DivMan, _А те которые сами подгружаются, то они не сортируются_ - значит очевидно проблема в данных! Смотри чем отличаются массивы которые ты делал вручную от тех которые есть на самом деле

Comment: Короче я сделал по возрастанию, а потом сделал реверс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть метод **[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** - на месте сортирует элементы массива и возвращает отсортированный массив.

Синтаксис

```
arr.sort([compareFunction])
```

где, `compareFunction` - необязательный параметр. Указывает функцию, определяющую порядок сортировки.

```js
var arr = [
    ['26', 'firstname1', 'lastname1'],
    ['14', 'firstname2', 'lastname2'],
    ['22', 'firstname3', 'lastname3'],
    ['23', 'firstname4', 'lastname4'],
    ['20', 'firstname5', 'lastname5']
];

arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a < b; // по убыванию
   //  return a[0] > b[0]; // по возрастанию
});


arr.forEach(function(el){
 console.log(el);
});
```